# Unknown provider returned from registerWithProvider

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to create a custom auth provider called "cgpsauth" and I am getting "Unknown provider" when I call:

```
  var ru = Realm.Sync.User.registerWithProvider(
        "http://localhost:9080",
        "cgpsauth",
        accessToken,
        (error, user) => {...
```

Here is my provider which I know is being loaded because if I make a syntax error in this file I get an error when I launch the ROS:

```
module.exports = function(deps) {
  return class CgpsAuthProvider extends deps.BaseAuthProvider {

    static get name() {
      return 'custom/cgpsauth';
    }

    constructor(name, options, requestPromise) {
      super(name, options, requestPromise);
    }

    verifyIdentifier(req) {
      const token = req.body.data;
      return 30;
    }
  }
};
```

configuration.yml

```
 providers:
     custom/cgpsauth:
      implementation: cgpsauth.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to prefix the provider name when authenticating from the client SDK with `custom/`:

```
var ru = Realm.Sync.User.registerWithProvider(
    "http://localhost:9080",
    "custom/cgpsauth",
    accessToken,
    (error, user) => {...
```